# URLEncodeUtils.format alternative while using HTTPUrlConnection Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm switching from apache Http client to Android UrlConnection. I have the following code:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> httpParams = new ArrayList<>();
formName = "somename";
httpParams.add(new Pair<>("formFileName", formName));    
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(httpParams, "utf-8");
URL httpGet = new URL("http://" + IP_ADDRESS + "/SOMEPATH/" + SERVLET_NAME + "?" + paramString + "&api=2");
```

My question is how is `URLEncodedUtils.format(httpParams, "utf-8")` can be replaced ? Thanks in advance

**UPD:** currently I've wrote my own function that formats the parameters in needed form. So the question is did I reinvented the wheel?